# What is the analogue for map_dfr function to bind vectors into matrix and run in parallel?

Tags: r, matrix, functional-programming

If I have a lot of calculations that outputs to vectors like:

```
calories    protein        fat     carbs
[1,] 0.000138 0.07444444 0.01387755 0.1004082
      calories    protein         fat      carbs
[1,] 0.0002085 0.04555556 0.009795918 0.07836735
       calories    protein        fat      carbs
[1,] 0.00017125 0.05777778 0.01632653 0.08326531
     calories    protein        fat      carbs
[1,] 0.000136 0.07555556 0.01795918 0.09387755
     calories    protein        fat      carbs
[1,] 0.000164 0.04333333 0.01387755 0.09877551
       calories    protein       fat      carbs
[1,] 0.00019925 0.05888889 0.0122449 0.06612245
```

I want to run each calculation and bind it as row to a final matrix,
like I do it with `map_dfr` or `furrr::future_map_dfr` functions.

Please advise, as I want to apply the function for 1+e10 times and it should run in parallel.

Comment: It looks like a `matrix`.  If it is a `vector`, then use `do.call(rbind, lst1)`

Comment: @akrun if I would run the same calculation and the output was a dataframe I would just use map_dfr or furrr::future_map_dfr function that would just bind all the outputs to one dataframe.
How can I do the same when my output is a named vector which I want to bind to a larger matrix at once?

Comment: @akrun, I am going to calculate billions of outputs, how can I run this process in parallel? I know it will be much faster with matrices compared to dataframes.

Comment: How long does each calculation take? If it's quick, I would not suggest parallelization. Instead, you should look at how to turn a vector into a matrix. Such as, `a <- runif(10); b <- matrix(a, nrow=2, ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)`

Comment: @Steves sorry, I forgot to reply to this.  What is the issue with `furrr`

Comment: @akrun furrr sometimes refuses to split the process to all my cores + it doesn't have the option to map_dfr for matrices I mean same process but for map_matrix and bind all the results into one big matrix.